# How to change cell background in html cell with handsontable?

Tags: handsontable

I set column property like this:

```
columns: [
    {data: "data", renderer: "html"},
]
```

then, I set background color of cell like this:

```
cell: [
    {renderer: customRenderer}
]
```

in customRender I have set cell background. Unfortunetly as a result I get cell with proper background color, but without html render. How can merge this two render types or how to set color cell in html?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the renderers using type property.

Set column property as:

```
columns:[
  {data: "data", type: {renderer: htmlRenderer}}
]
```

And set cell property as:

```
cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};    
        cellProperties.type = {renderer: greenRenderer}
        return cellProperties;
}
```

Please refer to fiddle for similar scenario **http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/rmnzcwkr/**

Comment: @Michal, are you fine with the answer? Do I need to elaborate more?